# CSS Sprite - clickable <a> within <li>

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I used an online Sprite Generator to create the html, css, and PNG.  Having trouble implementing the suggested code.

my original html

```
        <div class="main">
            <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img01" width="165" height="165"><h2>Boots</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img02" width="165" height="165"><h2>Shoes</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img03" width="165" height="165"><h2>Clogs</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="img05" width="165" height="165"><h2>Belts</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="img06" width="165" height="165"><h2>Hats &amp; Caps</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="img07" width="165" height="165"><h2>Sunglasses</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="img08" width="165" height="165"><h2>Scarves</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="img09" width="165" height="165"><h2>Casual</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="img10" width="165" height="165"><h2>Luxury</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg" alt="img11" width="165" height="165"><h2>Sport</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg" alt="img12" width="165" height="165"><h2>Carry-Ons</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="img13" width="165" height="165"><h2>Duffel Bags</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg" alt="img14" width="165" height="165"><h2>Laptop Bags</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg" alt="img15" width="165" height="165"><h2>Briefcases</h2></a></li>
                </ul>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#">Test1</a>
                    <a href="#">Test2</a>
                    <a href="#">Test3</a>
                    <a href="#">Test4</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

generated css

```
.sprite {background:url('../images/sprite.png') no-repeat top left; width: 165px; height: 165px;} 
.sprite.1 {background-position:0px 0px;} 
.sprite.2 {background-position:0px -175px;} 
.sprite.3 {background-position:0px -350px;} 
.sprite.4 {background-position:0px -525px;} 
.sprite.5 {background-position:0px -700px;} 
.sprite.6 {background-position:0px -875px;} 
.sprite.7 {background-position:0px -1050px;} 
.sprite.8 {background-position:0px -1225px;} 
.sprite.9 {background-position:0px -1400px;} 
.sprite.10 {background-position:0px -1575px;} 
.sprite.11 {background-position:0px -1750px;} 
.sprite.12 {background-position:0px -1925px;} 
.sprite.13 {background-position:0px -2100px;} 
.sprite.14 {background-position:0px -2275px;} 
.sprite.15 {background-position:0px -2450px;}
```

generated html

```
<div class='sprite 1'></div>
<div class='sprite 2'></div>
<div class='sprite 3'></div>
<div class='sprite 4'></div>
<div class='sprite 5'></div>
<div class='sprite 6'></div>
<div class='sprite 7'></div>
<div class='sprite 8'></div>
<div class='sprite 9'></div>
<div class='sprite 10'></div>
<div class='sprite 11'></div>
<div class='sprite 12'></div>
<div class='sprite 13'></div>
<div class='sprite 14'></div>
<div class='sprite 15'></div>
```

The best I can do is return the first image and it returns sprite 1 for all three of the images.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite 1"></div><h2>Boots</h2></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite 2"></div><h2>Shoes</h2></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite 3"></div><h2>Clogs</h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the problem here again? The a's of yours are in fact clickable

Comment: I tried <li class="sprite.1"><a href="#"><h2>Boots</h2></a></li> and <li class="sprite 1"><a href="#"><h2>Boots</h2></a></li> the image does not appear.

Comment: @Applebough...your are correct....the a's are clickable, but no image appears to click. The only thing thats appears is the text between the  <h2> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that classes cannot start with numbers

use

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite sprite-1"></div><h2>Boots</h2></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite sprite-2"></div><h2>Shoes</h2></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="sprite sprite-3"></div><h2>Clogs</h2></a></li>
</ul>
```

and

```css
.sprite {background:url('../images/sprite.png') no-repeat top left; width: 165px; height: 165px;} 
.sprite.sprite-1 {background-position:0px 0px;} 
.sprite.sprite-2 {background-position:0px -175px;} 
.sprite.sprite-3 {background-position:0px -350px;}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.sprite {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.sprite.sprite-1 {
  background: red;
}

.sprite.sprite-2 {
  background: green;
}

.sprite.sprite-3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite sprite-1"></div>
<div class="sprite sprite-2"></div>
<div class="sprite sprite-3"></div>
```

Comment: Here's a good discussion of valid CSS class names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors

Comment: @codehorse, we were wrong. Since we are dealing with sprite images, we need to have an element that has specific dimensions to hold the correct part of the sprite. Adding the classes to the other elements that also contain text, means that their size cannot be fixed, and so other parts of the sprite might be visible ..

Comment: adding the addition sprite- has this working perfect.  I wonder why the generator suggested it the way it did.

Comment: I have an additional question....by replacing the img tag in the html is there any way to add the alt tag to the css?

Comment: @KurtMarshman nope. There is no notion of the `alt` attribute for CSS. But you could add a `title` attribute to the `div` element. It would create a tooltip on long hovers.. (*but if you are asking for text to appear if images is not loaded then no.. not possible*). If you describe why exactly you want it there might be tricks with `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements..

Comment: You answered the basic question of the alt tag when image does not appear. There is a stess in seo to put something relevant in the alt att. Never thought of putting a title in the div.  What I would want to put in a pseudo element is what I would put in for the alt, but if the title in the div works...then I will just try it in there. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @KurtMarshman the title on the div would be more relevant for SEO purposes. The `:after`/`:before` trick would only matter to a viewer of the site, not a search engine as it would ignore it..